# Multiple calls using AsyncHttpResponseHandler

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

I am working on an app that loads a list of json data from a website, into a list.  Within that list, each item has an image associated with it.  The MediaAdapter works with each row, and calls an async load for each image.

The issue comes erratically.  Currently there are 3 items in the list (and 3 images).  Sometimes I will receive 1 image back, other time 2.  Rarely do I receive all 3 images back.  I have set up logging and have traced what I can without cracking open android-async-http.

In the logging below, note that onStart is called for joe_thumb__804587.jpg, but I never receive an exception or any further updates on that request.

Here is some code, and some logging.

The Media Adapter (Note: MediaLoader.fetchBinary is a pass thru to the BinaryNetworkClass):

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = ((Activity)this.getContext()).getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.media_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView keywords = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.keywords);
        ImageView thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        keywords.setText(getItem(position).getKeywords());

        fetchThumbnailsInView(thumb, getItem(position).getDefaultThumbnailUrl());

        return convertView;
    }


    private void fetchThumbnailsInView(final ImageView imageView, final String url) {

        String[] split = url.split("/");

        final String fileName = split[split.length - 1];

        MediaLoader.fetchBinary(url, new NetworkClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void success(Object data) {

                if (data instanceof byte[]) {

                    byte[] imageData = (byte[]) data;
                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Setting  fileName: " + fileName + " for imageView: " + imageView.toString());
                }
                else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "Didn't receive a byte array for url: " + url);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(throwable));
            }
        });
    }
```

The BinaryNetworkClass:

```
public class BinaryNetworkClient {
    private static final AsyncHttpClient mHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    private static final String TAG = "BinaryNetworkClient";

    public static void getData(final String url, final NetworkClientListener<byte[]> listener){
        String[] split = url.split("/");

        final String fileName = split[split.length - 1];

        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting BINARY data for fileName: " + fileName);

        mHttpClient.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Received BINARY data for fileName: " + fileName);

                    listener.success(responseBody);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Requesting BINARY FAILED for fileName: " + fileName);

                    listener.failure(error);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry() {
                super.onRetry();
                Log.i(TAG, "Retry called for fileName: " + fileName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                Log.i(TAG, "Start called for fileName: " + fileName);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                super.onFinish();
                Log.i(TAG, "Finish called for fileName: " + fileName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgress(int bytesWritten, int totalSize) {
                super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);

                Log.i(TAG, "OnProgress called for fileName: " + fileName + " (" + bytesWritten + " / " +  totalSize + ") ");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And here is some logging:

```
D/MARK﹕ Requesting BINARY data for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg
D/MARK﹕ Requesting BINARY data for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg
D/MARK﹕ Requesting BINARY data for fileName: joe_thumb__804587.jpg
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Start called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Start called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (2470 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (6566 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (10662 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (14758 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (18854 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (22950 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (27046 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (31142 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg (31687 / 31687)
D/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Received BINARY data for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg
D/MARK﹕ Setting  fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg for imageView: android.widget.ImageView{52a39304 V.ED.... ......ID 0,33-345,228 #7f07003f app:id/photo}
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Finish called for fileName: joe_thumb__188454.jpg
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (2470 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (6566 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (8150 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (12246 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (16342 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (18886 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Start called for fileName: joe_thumb__804587.jpg
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (22982 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (27078 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (31174 / 31687)
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ OnProgress called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg (31687 / 31687)
D/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Received BINARY data for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg
D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 541K, 8% free 7376K/7996K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
D/MARK﹕ Setting  fileName: joe_thumb.jpg for imageView: android.widget.ImageView{52a3b720 V.ED.... ......ID 0,33-345,228 #7f07003f app:id/photo}
I/BinaryNetworkClient﹕ Finish called for fileName: joe_thumb.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/536

Requires an update to the 1.4.5-SNAPSHOT library (I was using 1.4.4).

Once updated, everything is working as expected.